# SPSS: test if an interval between two dates contains a second interval

Tags: date, intervals, spss

I'm working on a project that requires me to use SPSS. I'm more comfortable with R, but I need to stay within the SPSS environment, and I won't be able to use the R plugin.

My problem relates to fiscal-years, and adjusting for the additional day they introduce. For example:

```
* fake data to permit syntax to be run.
data list free/number.
begin data
1
12
123
1234
12345
end data.

* calculate the number of days between the start/end of a fiscal year.
* this period contains a leap-day that I need to adjust for, but it returns 365.
compute begin1 = date.mdy(10,01,1999).
compute end1   = date.mdy(09,30,2000).
compute diff1  = datediff(end1, begin1, "days").

* this calculation behaves as expected-- producing 29 days.
compute begin2 = date.mdy(02,01,2000).
compute end2   = date.mdy(03,01,2000).
compute diff2  = datediff(end2, begin2, "days").
execute.
```

To get around the problem I'm experiencing with `datediff()`, I was planning on just adding a day if a row's interval between begin/end contains 2/28 and 3/1, during a leap year. However, I'm not sure of the best way to do this in SPSS. I've checked some SPSS list-servs, but haven't seen a solution to this type of test/calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datediff()` calculates the difference between two dates, which means the beginning date (or end date - depends how you look at it) is not included in the count.
You would get a count of 366 like you expected if you calculated the difference between (10,01,1999) and (10,01,2000), and the expected 365 days in non leap years, e.g. (10,01,2000) and (10,01,2001).

In your second example, calculating for February only, you calculated the difference between (02,01,2000) and (03,01,2000), getting 29 days. If you calculated the difference between (02,01,2000) and (02,29,2000) you would get 28 days and not 29...

So if you prefer to keep calculating the difference between the beginning and end of the year, just add 1 to your calculation.

Answer (score 1):

As eli-k says, datediff calculates the actual calendar interval.  It knows the rules for leap years, which are more complicated than just years divisble by 4.